# php HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD_POST addHeader used twice will it append or replace

Tags: php, xml, httprequest

I am using REQUEST.PHP
In the context of the PHP code below, does addHeader append to the header or overwrite it, i.e. or should I merge the addHeader lines into one line?  Maybe it's me but I could not find a clear answer in the manual.  I need to send all of the info in the header.

```
require 'HTTP/Request.php';

// <snip>

$r = new HTTP_Request($dest_url) or die("$dest_url: $php_errormsg");
$r->setMethod(HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD_POST);
$r->addHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
$r->addHeader("Authorization: Basic:" . $authheader, 'text/xml');
$r->addRawPostData($packet);
$res = $r->sendRequest() or die("sendRequest:". $php_errormsg);
if ($r->getResponseCode() == 200) {
  header('Content-Type: text/xml');
}
```

etc.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation?

Comment: If it only allows you to add one header at a time, I think it's pretty clear that it has to append, not replace. Otherwise, how would you set more than one header?

Comment: Is this the PEAR HTTP class?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-request.headers.php) says:

> Adding additional headers to the HTTP request.

The word "adding" means that these append to the header, they don't replace it.

Also, it says "headers", which is plural, which implies that you can call it multiple times to add an additional header each time. If each time just replaced the header, you could only add one.

Comment: I reviewed the code and docs before posting.  I became unsure if the addheader function added a 2nd header or appended (add to) the existing header.  REQUEST.php is an add-on to PEAR.  I needed to tweak for PHP 7 but it works.

Comment: Note also that it uses the plural "headers". If it could only add a second header, it would be singular.